# Splitting a csv files with inconsistent column numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV file that is formatted like below, except it is some 20 million lines:

```
A,B,C,D
1,2,3,4
1,1,3,4
1,0,0,1,4,3
1,0,5,6,2,1
```

Which I try to read with pandas like this:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(_out_path, sep=',', engine='c') # engine c because it's faster
```

Which causes the following error:

```py
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 18 fields in line 13674206, saw 31
```

With the test file above pandas handles this and adds two unnamed columns which contain np.NAN for the first two rows.

```
A   B   C   D   Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5
0   1   2   3   4   NaN NaN
1   1   1   3   4   NaN NaN
2   1   0   0   1   4.0 3.0
3   1   0   5   6   2.0 1.0
```

However, for the real file (which I, unfortunately, can't share), it causes the above error.

I'm looking for a way to work around it by finding the row with the most commas, count the Nr of commas and append as many commas as the need to every row so that pandas will read the file.
Or ideally for a simpler way to read the file anyways.

---

Edit:

The Data has been concatenated from some hundred of CSV files but in the middle new columns were added (unfortunately not all at the end).
So a good solution (thanks for the comments) would be to split the file where the nr of entries changes.

Also, there are no headers in the file. I tried adding them manually in the first row for this example, so I guess I will have to add the headers after splitting the file.

Comment: If you don't need the extra columns, you could try `usecols=[0,1,2,3]`. Alternatively, you can skip and log the bad lines with `error_bad_lines=False warn_bad_lines=True`. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html

Comment: Apparently this is a merge of a coule hundred csvs. Add some point they started adding more data columns... unfortunately it was added somewhere in the middle and now the data I need has become shifted.

My idea was to split to data frame with using a conditional of the extra column being na or not and then rearranging the columns.

Alternatively I could split the CSV file accoridng to the nr of commas per row, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: This is atrocious. Whoever decided this data should be concatenated deserves to be sanctioned. If you're willing to word the question so that it asks for splitting the data, I would be willing to write up an answer. It would be good to know whether there are new headers at the rows where the column count goes up or whether it's only numbers after the first line.

Comment: I edited the question to add splitting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have clean sets of data, it's best to split them into separate files.

If the number of columns only ever goes up and never down, you can easily keep track of the different destination files with a dictionary:

```
source_file = open('mixed_data.csv', 'r')

destination_files = {}

for line in source_file:
    item_count = len(line.split(','))

    try:
        dest_file = destination_files[item_count]

    except KeyError:
        file_name = 'split_data_' + str(item_count) + '.csv'
        dest_file = destination_files[item_count] = open(file_name, 'w')

    dest_file.write(line)

for dest_file in destination_files.values():
    dest_file.close()

source_file.close()
```

The closing is not strictly necessary if the program ends right afterwards or the scope where the file objects are bound is left, but it's good practice anyway.

Comment: I suspect that could take some time with tens of millions of lines. There are optional arguments to `open()` where different kinds of buffering can be configured (if the version of Python isn't too old) which may or may not be able to speed it up a bit.